# Flask gives malformed communication packet with mysql-connector-python 8.0.22

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-connector-python

mysql-connector-python 8.0.22
Works fine alone
But gives me with Flask

> Malformed communication packet

For the same code I can run it in python small file but not with Flask

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(database="XXXXX", user="XXXXX", password="XXXXX", host="XXXXX")
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
cursor.execute("""
SELECT * FROM category category
WHERE 1
""", tuple([]))
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

[image: Error Flask mysql-connector-python malformed communication packet]

Comment: try to use sql alchemy, flask has a package for it, and it will abstract a lot of things to you, like database transactions.

I am using these packages with versions, SQLAlchemy==1.3.13, Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1, mysqlclient==2.0.1

Comment: There's already software built on top of Flask and mysql-connector-python so we need a solution not workaround. This is not a solution, It's not logic to change software data access layer for just an issue appeared in driver/library due to some updates from MySQL side last days. You can't guarantee even sqlalchemy itself not affected or will not be affected with database/driver/library updates and seek again for a reengineering work to change from sqlalchemy to something else. Software industry don't work like that. There's always a better solution. Thanks for your opinion.